# drawing program whiteboard not appearing?

Tags: java, drawing

Ok, so I have this assignment that tells me to make a drawing program with buttons that can draw shape operates like "Painter" drawing program on the computer. The problem is that I can't even make the white board to appear even though I follow the code of a similar java program I found on the internet.
So here's my code:

Main class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main
{
private static final Toolkit TOOLKIT;
static
{
    TOOLKIT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
}
private Main()
{
}

public static void main(final String[] argv)
{
    final ShapeFrame frame;

    frame = new ShapeFrame();
    position(frame);
    frame.init();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private static void position(final JFrame frame)
{
    final Dimension size;

    size = calculateScreenArea(0.80f,
                               0.80f);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setLocation(centreOnScreen(size));
}

/**
 * the amount of center on screen
 * @param size space size.
 * @return the complete calculated space.
 */
public static Point centreOnScreen(final Dimension size)
{
    final Dimension screenSize;

    if(size == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be null");
    }

    screenSize = TOOLKIT.getScreenSize();

    return (new Point((screenSize.width - size.width) / 2,
                      (screenSize.height - size.height) / 2));
}

/**
 * method that calculating screen area.
 * @param widthPercent width percentage.
 * @param heightPercent height percentage.
 * @return dimension the dimension.
 */
public static Dimension calculateScreenArea(final float widthPercent,
                                            final float heightPercent)
{
    final Dimension screenSize;
    final Dimension area;
    final int       width;
    final int       height;
    final int       size;

    if((widthPercent <= 0.0f) || (widthPercent > 100.0f))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("widthPercent cannot be " + 
                                           "<= 0 or > 100 - got: " +
                                           widthPercent);
    }

    if((heightPercent <= 0.0f) || (heightPercent > 100.0f))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("heightPercent cannot be " + 
                                           "<= 0 or > 100 - got: " +
                                           heightPercent);
    }

    screenSize = TOOLKIT.getScreenSize();
    width      = (int)(screenSize.width * widthPercent);
    height     = (int)(screenSize.height * heightPercent);
    size       = Math.min(width,
                          height);
    area       = new Dimension(size,
                               size);

    return (area);
}
    }
```

my JFrame class:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Container;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Event;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import javax.swing.Box;
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
 import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
 import javax.swing.JToolBar;
 import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
 import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

 /**
  * This class creates the painting program's toolbar, buttons and stuffs.
  * @author Fu Han
  * @version 1.0
  */
 public class ShapeFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
     private DrawPad drawPad;
     /**
      * the constant string 'save'.
      */
     static final private String SAVE = "Save";
     /**
      * the constant string 'save as'.
      */
     static final private String SAVE_AS = "Save As";
     /**
      * the constant string 'new'.
      */
     static final private String NEW = "New";
     /**
      * the constant string 'color'.
      */
     static final private String color = "Color";
     /**
      * string oval for easy access for buttons.
      */
     static String oval = new String("oval");
     /**
      * string line for easy access for buttons.
      */
     static String line = new String("line");
     /**
      * string circle for easy access for buttons.
      */
     static String circle = new String("circle");
     /**
      * string rectangle for easy access for buttons.
      */
     static String rectangle = new String("rectangle");
     /**
      * string square for easy access for buttons.
      */
     static String square = new String("square");
     /**
      * ShapeFrame constructor.
      */
    public ShapeFrame(){
        super();
    }
    /**
      * method that add buttons.
      * @param toolBar Jtoolbar.
      * @param btn Jbuttons.
      */
     protected void addButtons(JToolBar toolBar, JButton btn) {
         toolBar.add(btn);
     }

     /**
      * method that add radio buttons.
      * @param toolBar Jtoolbar.
      * @param btn JRadioButton.
      */
     protected void addRadioButtons(JToolBar toolBar, JRadioButton btn) {
         toolBar.add(btn); 
     }

     /**
      * method that creates button.
      * @param btnNam button name.
      * @param actionCommand calling from string constant.
      * @param toolTipText the message that will appear if cursor was hover over.
     * @param altText alternative text.
     * @return button Jbutton.
     */
    protected JButton btnmaker(String btnNam, String actionCommand, String toolTipText,      String altText) {

   //Create and initialize the button.
     JButton button = new JButton(btnNam);
    button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
   button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
      button.addActionListener(this);
    return button;
}

/**
 * action performed when clicked button.
 * @param e mouse click.
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you have clicked the button");
}

/**
 * editlistener for menu bar.
 * @author Fu Han
 *
 */
private class EditListener implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * action performed when clicking menu button.
     * @param e mouse click.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
/**
 * radio listener for the radio buttons.
 * @author 
 *
 */
    private class RadioListener implements ActionListener{
        /**
        * action performed when click the button.
        * @param e mouse click.
        */
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 String factoryName = null;
  System.out.print("ActionEvent received: ");
   if (e.getActionCommand() == oval) {
    System.out.println(oval + " pressed.");
    drawPad.setCurrentShape(oval);
    }else if(e.getActionCommand() == rectangle){
    System.out.println(rectangle + " pressed.");
    drawPad.setCurrentShape(rectangle);
    }else if(e.getActionCommand() == square){
    System.out.println(square + " pressed.");
    drawPad.setCurrentShape(square);
    }else{
    System.out.println(line + " pressed.");}
    drawPad.setCurrentShape(line);
    }

 /**
  * method for when changes happened after clicking.
  * @param e mouse click.
  */
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

 }
 }
 /**
  * method for when changes of states that happened after clicking.
  * @param e mouse click.
  */
 public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

 }

 /**
  * method for selecting color.
  */
 private void selectColor(){
     Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(
        ShapeFrame.this,
        "Choose New Background Color",
        Color.RED);
 }

/**
 * GUI initialization.
 */
public void init(){

    Container content = getContentPane();
    //Creates a new container
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //sets the layout

    final DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();
    //creates a new padDraw, which is pretty much the paint program

    content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    EditListener l = new EditListener();
    JMenu filem = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem mi;
    mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("New", 'n'));
    mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mi.addActionListener(l);
    mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Open", 'o'));
    mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mi.addActionListener(l);
    mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Save", 's'));
    mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mi.addActionListener(l);
    mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Save As", 'a'));
    mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mi.addActionListener(l);
    mi = filem.add(new JMenuItem("Exit", 'e'));
    mi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mi.addActionListener(l);  

    JMenu shapem = new JMenu("Shape");
    JMenuItem smi;
    smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Line", 'l'));
    smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    smi.addActionListener(l);
    smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Circle", 'c'));
    smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    smi.addActionListener(l);
    smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Rectangle", 'r'));
    smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_U, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    smi.addActionListener(l);
    smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Square", 'q'));
    smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    smi.addActionListener(l);
    smi = shapem.add(new JMenuItem("Shape Picker", 'p'));
    smi.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, Event.CTRL_MASK));
    smi.addActionListener(l);

    menubar.add(filem);
    menubar.add(shapem);     
    menubar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());


    setJMenuBar(menubar);


    //Create the toolbar.
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton saveBtn = btnmaker("Save",SAVE, "save your paint", "Save");
    JButton saveAsBtn = btnmaker("Save As",SAVE_AS, "save your paint to?","Save As");
    JButton NewBtn = btnmaker("New",NEW,"new paint","New");

    JButton colorbtn = btnmaker("Color",color,"choose color","Color");
    colorbtn.setToolTipText("Click this button to select colors.");

    colorbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {              
            selectColor();
        }

    });



    RadioListener myListener = new RadioListener();
    JRadioButton ovalShape = new JRadioButton(oval);
    ovalShape.addActionListener(myListener);
    ovalShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    ovalShape.setActionCommand(oval);
    ovalShape.setSelected(true);
    add(ovalShape);

    JRadioButton rectangleShape = new JRadioButton(rectangle);
    rectangleShape.addActionListener(myListener);
    rectangleShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    rectangleShape.setActionCommand(rectangle);
    rectangleShape.setSelected(true);
    add(rectangleShape);

    JRadioButton squareShape = new JRadioButton(square);
    squareShape.addActionListener(myListener);
    squareShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    squareShape.setActionCommand(square);
    squareShape.setSelected(true);
    add(squareShape);

    JRadioButton lineShape = new JRadioButton(line);
    lineShape.addActionListener(myListener);
    lineShape.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    lineShape.setActionCommand(line);
    add(lineShape);


    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(ovalShape);
    group.add(lineShape);
    group.add(rectangleShape);
    group.add(squareShape);

    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar("File");
    JToolBar toolBar2 = new JToolBar("Shape",JToolBar.VERTICAL);
    JToolBar toolbar3 = new JToolBar("colors",JToolBar.VERTICAL);


    addButtons(toolBar,saveBtn);
    addButtons(toolBar,saveAsBtn);
    addButtons(toolBar,NewBtn);
    addRadioButtons(toolBar2,ovalShape);
    addRadioButtons(toolBar2,lineShape);
    addRadioButtons(toolBar2,rectangleShape);
    addRadioButtons(toolBar2,squareShape);
    addButtons(toolbar3,colorbtn);


    panel.add(toolBar);
    panel2.add(toolBar2);
    panel2.add(toolbar3);


    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    content.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
}
 }
```

the DrawPad class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class DrawPad extends JComponent{
    Image image;
    //this is gonna be your image that you draw on
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
    Shape shape;
    //this is what we'll be using to draw on
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
    //these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates
    String currentShape;

    public String getCurrentShape() {
        return currentShape;
    }

    public void setCurrentShape(String currentShape) {
        this.currentShape = currentShape;
    }

    //Now for the constructors
    public DrawPad(){

        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                if(currentShape != null){
                    if(currentShape == "rectangle"){
                        shape = new Rectangle();
                    }else if(currentShape == "oval"){
                        shape = new Oval();
                    }else if(currentShape == "line"){
                        shape = new Line();
                    }else{
                        shape = new Square();
                    }
                    shape.setPoint1(e.getPoint());
                    shape.setColor(Color.black);
                }
            }
        });
        //if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
        //coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                shape.setPoint2(e.getPoint());
            }

        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //shape.Draw(g);
        if(image == null){
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();

        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    //this is the painting bit
    //if it has nothing on it then
    //it creates an image the size of the window
    //sets the value of Graphics as the image
    //sets the rendering
    //runs the clear() method
    //then it draws the image


    public void clear(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and here is the painter program that I look up to:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

class PadDraw extends JComponent{
    Image image;
    //this is gonna be your image that you draw on
    Graphics2D graphics2D;
    //this is what we'll be using to draw on
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
    //these are gonna hold our mouse coordinates

    //Now for the constructors
    public PadDraw(){
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });
        //if the mouse is pressed it sets the oldX & oldY
        //coordinates as the mouses x & y coordinates
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                if(graphics2D != null)
                graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                repaint();
                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }

        });
        //while the mouse is dragged it sets currentX & currentY as the mouses x and y
        //then it draws a line at the coordinates
        //it repaints it and sets oldX and oldY as currentX and currentY
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if(image == null){
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();

        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
    //this is the painting bit
    //if it has nothing on it then
    //it creates an image the size of the window
    //sets the value of Graphics as the image
    //sets the rendering
    //runs the clear() method
    //then it draws the image


    public void clear(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
    //this is the clear
    //it sets the colors as white
    //then it fills the window with white
    //thin it sets the color back to black
    public void red(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.red);
        repaint();
    }
    //this is the red paint
    public void black(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
    //black paint
    public void magenta(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.magenta);
        repaint();
    }
    //magenta paint
    public void blue(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
        repaint();
    }
    //blue paint
    public void green(){
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.green);
        repaint();
    }
    //green paint

}
```

main method for the drawing program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class paint{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Icon iconB = new ImageIcon("blue.gif");
        //the blue image icon
        Icon iconM = new ImageIcon("magenta.gif");
        //magenta image icon
        Icon iconR = new ImageIcon("red.gif");
        //red image icon
        Icon iconBl = new ImageIcon("black.gif");
        //black image icon
        Icon iconG = new ImageIcon("green.gif");
        //finally the green image icon
        //These will be the images for our colors.

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint It");
        //Creates a frame with a title of "Paint it"

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        //Creates a new container
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //sets the layout

        final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();
        //creates a new padDraw, which is pretty much the paint program

        content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //sets the padDraw in the center

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //creates a JPanel
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(32, 68));
        //This sets the size of the panel

        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        //creates the clear button and sets the text as "Clear"
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.clear();
            }
        });
        //this is the clear button, which clears the screen.  This pretty
        //much attaches an action listener to the button and when the
        //button is pressed it calls the clear() method

        JButton redButton = new JButton(iconR);
        //creates the red button and sets the icon we created for red
        redButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.red();
            }

        });
        //when pressed it will call the red() method.  So on and so on =]

        JButton blackButton = new JButton(iconBl);
        //same thing except this is the black button
        blackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.black();
            }
        });

        JButton magentaButton = new JButton(iconM);
        //magenta button
        magentaButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.magenta();
            }
        });

        JButton blueButton = new JButton(iconB);
        //blue button
        blueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.blue();
            }
        });

        JButton greenButton = new JButton(iconG);
        //green button
        greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                drawPad.green();
            }
        });
        blackButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        magentaButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        redButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        blueButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        greenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(16,16));
        //sets the sizes of the buttons

        panel.add(greenButton);
        panel.add(blueButton);
        panel.add(magentaButton);
        panel.add(blackButton);
        panel.add(redButton);
        panel.add(clearButton);
        //adds the buttons to the panel

        content.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //sets the panel to the left

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        //sets the size of the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //makes it so you can close
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //makes it so you can see it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #1

Maintaining a reference to the `Graphics` context and painting outside of a paint cycle. Never maintain a reference to a `Graphics` context that you did not create yourself. Never paint to a component's `Graphics` context outside of the `paintComponent` method call. Painting is destructive, anything drawn to the `Graphics` context outside of the paint cycle will be lost

## Problem #2

Breaking the paint chain. Unless you a VERY good reason to do otherwise, you should always call `super.paintComponent` BEFORE you perform any custom painting. Also `paintComponent` never needs to be public, no one should ever be calling it...

## Problem #3

`currentShape == "line"` is not how `String` comparison works. Use `"line".equals(currentShape)` instead...

## Problem #4

`setDoubleBuffered(false);`...this just means a lot more work for you...paint to the `Graphics` context which is passed to the `paintComponent`, WHEN it's passed to the paintComponent method...

## Problem #5

Beware of what you are adding what to...

```
Container content = getContentPane();
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

final DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();

content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//...

//Create the toolbar.
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

//...
// What do you think this is been added to?
add(ovalShape);
//...
// What do you think this is been added to?
add(rectangleShape);
//...
// What do you think this is been added to?
add(squareShape);
//...
// What do you think this is been added to?
add(lineShape);

//...

panel.add(toolBar);
panel2.add(toolBar2);
panel2.add(toolbar3);

content.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

`BorderLayout` will only show the last item that was added to any of it's five available slots...which would, in this case, `lineShape`...

## Take a look at...

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

## Recommendations

Prototype small elements of your problem, understand how the work in isolation and then figure out how to plug them into a large set of functionality...